# Using an 8 speed cassette on an 10-11 speed Tiagra FH-RS400

Tags: shimano, cassette, touring, wheel-building, tiagra

I'm trying to build a new set of wheels for touring trip (2 months) I have planned and can only find a Tiagra FH-RS400 hub. The issues is that my shifters are Claris 3x8 ST-2403-L and cannot support 10 or 11 speed.

Can I use an 8 speed cassette on the Tiagra hub and if so what size spacer would I need?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The spacer you need is 1.85mm. Web search for '11 speed hub spacer' yields what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hub for 8 to 10 speed are the same. You are good to go. You should not need any spacer for them.

However, if you mean this hub https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/tiagra-4700/FH-RS400.html they say it is a 10/11 speed hub and hence you need a (1.85 mm, as mentioned in a comment) spacer for 8 to 10 speed for this one. Those are included by some shops.

Because it is a Shimano hub you can also verify the compatibility in the official chart https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-454

A similar hub which is simply 8/9/10 speed would be (Sora) FH-RS300. It could also be cheaper.

Comment: For touring it's probably best to avoid the cheapest parts

Comment: @ojs I do not believe there is anything wrong with Shimano hubs at this level. It is certainly is not anything cheapest one could buy. I see the listed price for RS300 is 30€, for RS400 it is 40€. One could go much cheaper and Shimano hubs have good reputation in general. And I never said the OP should buy RS300, I poited it out as an alternative that is made for 8 speed without a spacer.

Comment: In his time, Sheldon Brown really recommended the Tiagra hubs https://www.bikeforums.net/bicycle-mechanics/204754-tiagra-hub-quality.html?204754-Tiagra-hub-quality=#post2678928 Of course, a lot might have changed since then. But the reputation of Shimano hubs in general is great. The price level to chose is up to everyone's individual choice.

Comment: I you pay attention, you'll notice that Tiagra is not the bargain series (that is Sora). In my experience there was large difference between the cheapest and mid-tier Shimano hubs, and as you already noticed, the price difference is 10 to 20 €.

Comment: @ojs If you pay attention *"I never said the OP should buy RS300, I pointed it out as an alternative that is made for 8 speed without a spacer."* *"The price level to choose is up to everyone's individual choice."*

Comment: Due to the difficulty of finding hubs in my area I am pretty limited in my selection. I managed to buy a FH-RS400. My budget was around $50 usd but finding hubs for that cheap in the US can be tough. I really appreciate the quick responses!

Comment: @ojs I agree skimping on parts can lead some issues down the line but I have heard and experienced good quality from even the low end of Shimano. The main reason I was looking for the lower end was to match my lower end shifters and crankset.

Comment: @VladimirF I paid attention and I never claimed you recommended the cheapest stuff. I hope we're clear now.